# Showing activity indicator using SplitlViewController

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

We are trying to show an activity indicator while loading table view data in the master view of our SplitViewController.  This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29913615/47281) works well but only when viewing just the Master view.  When in split view the indicator doesn't appear.  How can you tweak this solution when showing the split view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick was to reference `self.splitViewController.view` instead of `self.view`:

```
let split = self.splitViewController!
indicator.center = split.view.center
split.view.addSubview(indicator)
```